# What is the difference in use static import and create new q-type instance using QueryDSL?

Tags: java, querydsl

I saw in production code line like this:

```
public Info findById(final long id){
 QInfo info = QInfo.info;
 JPAQuery query = newJpaQuery().from(info);
 .....
}
```

and on the other:

```
import static com.example.system.app.entities.QApplication.application;

public Application findById(final long id){
        return newJpaQuery().from(application).where(application.applicationId.eq(id)).uniqueResult(application);
    }
```

what is the difference in use of using static import and create Q-instance for every method? Is the root of this comes from some thread-safe observations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q-instances are threadsafe, but sometimes you need multiple variables in a query for the same type.

In general if you need only one variable per type, the default variables are sufficient, if you need more, you will need to create additional variables.

Those additional variables can be created per query or as constants.

e.g.

```
QInfo info = QInfo.info; // default variable
QInfo info2 = new QInfo("info2"); // extra variable
newJpaQuery().from(info).innerJoin(info.path, info2).where(...)
```

Comment: So if I need one Q-instance per class I can use it in the every method in that class and use static import, and do not warry about multithreading?